# Checkbox update ONLY

Tags: php, html

I have an issue with my code because when I press the update button I want it to display on the redirected page only the field that are checked in the checkbox.

I will post the code from the first page , then the code from the second page , where the update code is and some pictures of the website page .

First page :

[firstpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnwRo.png)

code firstpage:

```
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['search'])){

    $ValueToSearch=$_POST['valueToSearch'];
    $query1="SELECT * FROM `customer` AS cust,`type` AS type,`valability` AS val WHERE cust.Customer_ID=val.Customer_ID  AND val.Insurance_ID=type.Insurance_ID AND CONCAT(cust.Customer_ID,cust.Employee_ID,cust.Name_c,cust.Surname_c,cust.brth,cust.phone,cust.adress,cust.email,type.series,type.type,type.name_i,type.Company_N,type.value,val.nr,val.entry_d,val.exp_d)  LIKE '%".$ValueToSearch."%'"; 
    echo "<!-- ". $query1 ." -->";
    $search_result=filterTable($query1);
}else{


     $query1 = "SELECT * FROM `customer`,`type`,`valability` WHERE customer.Customer_ID=valability.Customer_ID  AND valability.Insurance_ID=type.Insurance_ID";
     $search_result=filterTable($query1);


    }
function filterTable($query1){

    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root", "","asig");
    $filter_Result=mysqli_query($connect,$query1);
    return $filter_Result;
}


?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
//$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost"   ,"root", "","asig");
//$update_id=$_POST['checkbox'];    



    Header("Location: displayupdate.php");
    //die();
    //exit;
}else{
    echo"can't redirect";
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Display Table </title>
      <style>
           table {
             width: 100%;    
             background-color: #f1f1c1;
        }
     table ,tr, th, td
            {
               border:1px solid black;
               border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        th,td{
            padding: 5px;
        }

      </style>
   </head>


   <!--Beginning of CSS page--> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">


      <body>

      <div class="w3-display-container" style="margin-bottom:50px">
  <img src="image2/Insurance-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-container w3-amber w3-hover-orange w3-hide-small"
   style="bottom:10%;opacity:0.7;width:70%">
  <h2><b>4 Good Reasons<br>For being a SafeAsig client</b></h2>
</div>
</div>

      <!--Buton pentru display timp-->

      <button type="button"
       onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
       Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
        <p id="demo"></p>     





           <form action="display.php" method="post">
               <input type="text" name="valueToSearch" placeholder="ValueToSearch">
               <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter">
               <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete">
               <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
        <hr>       
                <h1 style="text-align:center;"> Date Clienti</h1>
                 <table>

                   <tr>
                    <th></th>
                      <th>id</th>
                      <th>Nume</th>
                      <th>Prenume</th>
                      <th>DataNastere</th>
                      <th>telefon</th>
                      <th>Adresa</th>
                      <th>email</th>
                      <th>serie</th>
                      <th>type</th>
                      <th>numeAsig</th>
                      <th>Companie</th>
                      <th>Valoare></th>
                      <th>Numar</th>
                      <th>DataIntrare</th>
                      <th>DataExpirare</th>

                   </tr>

                   <?php while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                   <tr>
                     <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['Customer_ID']; ?>"/></td>
             <td><?php echo $row['Customer_ID']; ?></td>

                         <td><?php echo $row['Name_c']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['Surname_c']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['brth']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['adress']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['series']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['type']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['name_i']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['Company_N']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['nr']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['entry_d']; ?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $row['exp_d']; ?></td>

                   </tr>
                   <?php endwhile;?>
                 </table>


           </form>

     <!--Link pentru inserari-->

      <a href="http://localhost/website/main_entry_page.php">Inserare Clienti </a> <br><br>
      <a href="http://localhost/website/insert_employee.php">Inserare angajati</a> <br><br>


<div class="w3-row w3-container" style="margin:50px 0">
<div class="w3-half w3-container">
  <div class="w3-topbar w3-border-amber">
    <img src="image2/profesionalism.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <h2>Profesionalism and dedication</h2>
    <p>Only for our clients , the best services provided.</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="w3-half w3-container">
  <div class="w3-topbar w3-border-amber">
    <img src="image2/protection.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <h2>100% protection</h2>
    <p>Up to 100% protection with our wide varaity insurances.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="w3-row w3-container" style="margin:50px 0">
<div class="w3-half w3-container">
  <div class="w3-topbar w3-border-orange">
    <img src="image2/stability.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <h2>Stability all times</h2>
    <p>Wherever you travel our services provide stability.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-half w3-container">
  <div class="w3-topbar w3-border-orange">
    <img src="image2/support.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <h2>For good and worst</h2>
    <p>Don't wait until it is to late.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<?php

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root", "","asig");
$del_id = $_POST['checkbox'];
while(list($key, $val) = @each($del_id)){
 mysqli_query($connect, "delete from customer where customer_id = $val");
}
}

?>






      </body>
</html>
```

picture second page:

[secondpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbs8q.png)

code second page:

```
<html>

<?php

//Connect to database
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root", "","asig");

//Select database
mysqli_select_db($connect,'asig');

//Select Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer`,`type`,`valability` WHERE customer.Customer_ID=valability.Customer_ID  AND valability.Insurance_ID=type.Insurance_ID";

//Execte query
$records=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);



?>


<head>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
         <th>id</th>
         <th>Nume</th>
         <th>Prenume</th>
         <th>DataNastere</th>
         <th>telefon</th>
         <th>Adresa</th>
         <th>email</th>
         <th>serie</th>
         <th>type</th>
         <th>numeAsig</th>
         <th>Companie</th>
         <th>Valoare></th>
         <th>Numar</th>
         <th>DataIntrare</th>
         <th>DataExpirare</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($records)){


                       echo "<tr><form action=update.php method=post>";
                      // echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=checkbox[]  value='".$row['Customer_ID']."'></td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=hidden name =id value='".$row['Customer_ID']."' ></td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name= name value='".$row['Name_c']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=prenume value='".$row['Surname_c']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=brth value='".$row['brth']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=phone value='".$row['phone']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=adress value='".$row['adress']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=email value='".$row['email']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=serie value='".$row['series']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=type value='".$row['type']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=namei value='".$row['name_i']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=compn value='".$row['Company_N']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=value value='".$row['value']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=nr value='".$row['nr']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=entryin value='".$row['entry_d']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=text name=entryout value='".$row['exp_d']."'> </td>";
                       echo "<td><input type=submit>";

                   echo "</form></tr>";



     }



    ?>  
</table>




</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your  action goes to display.php, I will assume that your 'second page' is display.php. If that is the case then you need to retrieve the submitted checked values with $_POST[].

In your example the check boxes are named 'checkbox' so your POST should look like below...

```
<?php

$customer_id_arr = $_POST['checkbox'];
$customer_id_str = implode(",", $customer_id_arr);

//Connect to database
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost" ,"root", "","asig");

//Select database
mysqli_select_db($connect,'asig');

//Select Query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer`,`type`,`valability` WHERE customer.Customer_ID IN(" . $customer_id_str . ")  AND valability.Insurance_ID=type.Insurance_ID";

//Execte query
$records=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

?>
<html>
```

Your code overall needs a good bit of work/cleanup.

Hope that helps.